# Intellij Community can't use http proxy for Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, intellij-idea

I have Intellij IDEA Community installed on a Linux box that needs to use an authenticated proxy to get to the Internet. I have a system-wide proxy on the box that works, and I have the proxy configured in ~/.m2/settings.xml.  Maven correctly uses the proxy  when I run try it from the command-line.

I have the same proxy configured within Intellij and it gives me the plugins listing correctly.  But when I try to sync with the Maven repository withing Intellij I keep getting this:

```
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:pom:2.2' 
from  repository restlet (http://maven.restlet.org): Authorization failed: Not   
authorized by proxy.
```

I went to Settings->Maven and put in the proxy info as properties and that didn't work.  I can see by looking at those settings that Intellij is reading my ~./m2/settings.xml fine because it knows where my local repo is (it's in a non-standard place).

Anyone know how I can get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commented out the proxy config in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file, let the Intellij Proxy info alone, and then supplied the properties in Setting->Maven.  Not sure why that worked (nor why the settings.xml wasn't working right) but it's working now.

Comment: And how is that different from what I suggested?

Comment: It's not -- I was just going to comment on it.

Commenting out the proxy config in the settings.xml just disabled the proxy altogether.  So I thought it was working but instead it was trying to connect, couldn't, and kept trying for a while. I figured this out after I left it run for two hours.  A maven update shouldn't take that long!

I didn't get the same error as above -- instead I got "Unable to connect to . . ". Which means that it didn't even get to the proxy.

anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 118):

1. Navigate to `Maven > Importing`<sup>*1*</sup>. inside the IntelliJ IDEA Settings (which is found under `File > Settings`).
2. The second last option in `Maven > Importing` is a field named "VM options for importer". Append the following to whatever already exists there:

   `-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=myproxy.com -DproxyPort=3128`

   Here, replace `myproxy.com` with your proxy server, (e.g. http://myproxyserver.com). Replace `3128` with your proxy port (e.g. 8080).
3. Do the same under `Maven > Runner`<sup>*1*</sup>
4. Apply and close the settings window.

It should work now.

---

<sup>*1*</sup> This may be nested under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools >`*, depending on the version of IntelliJ you're using.*

Comment: That worked for me, since I am behind a windows proxy, and need to have cntlm installed (I use a debian installation)... Thanks!

Comment: For those who have an SSL connection, you also need to add `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/myKeystores/.myNexusKeystore`

Comment: For me at least: no need to restart IntelliJ.

Comment: Why can't maven just consume the IDE's proxy? This should be a bug on Intellij.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this works with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 and newest plugin.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem running maven inside IntelliJ whilst behind an NTLM proxy. The working solution was as follows:

1. Download and install CNTLM. Excellent post here on how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23962313/3298801
2. Set and test your local proxy settings in IntelliJ via Settings >> System Settings >> HTTP Proxy.
3. In Intellij set the maven runner. Within Settings >> Maven >> runner set VM options to:
   `-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=localhost -DproxyPort=3132`
4. Restart Intellij
5. Note within ~/.m2/settings.xml I also added my proxy config as:

```xml
<proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <host>localhost</host>
            <port>3132</port> 
        </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348) link for detailed steps

Comment: adding proxy config to ~/.m2/settings.xml helped, thanks!

Comment: Changing VM options made no difference for me, but adding proxy config to ~/.m2/settings.xml fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

A little update for memo. I don't have a standalone maven installed, so finally I fixed this by modifying the maven plugin settings. settings.xml is located at :

**IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\settings.xml**

You can find proxy settings and change it as mentioned above.

Comment: This answer helped me most, because there is a complete settings.xml where I just need to enter the proxy settings.

Answer (score 6):

I meet the same problem.By ShadowsocksR,I can visit some websites that i can't visit without ShadowsocksR. I use Intellij , the error is "Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]".At last, I also added my proxy config as:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>1080</port>
      <username>***.***.**.***:****</username>
      <password>*******</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.baidu.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

My computer environment is win10. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 4):

Can you try either removing the proxy setting in *settings.xml* or the setting in IntelliJ itself.

And then try to sync with the maven repo from within Intellij.

Answer (score 3):

I just add it in the VM option in the run configuration, and it works

```
-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=proxy.com -DproxyPort=3132
```

inside the IntelliJ IDEA -> edit configuration ->click on modify option -> Add VM options and add it, replace "proxy.com" with your proxy server (e.g. `http://myproxyserver.com`)

Answer (score 1):

I Have found similar issues with the Maven 2.2 integration in intellij 9.
I am using 9.0.1

I use intellij behind a corporate firewall/proxy.
If I point Intellij's maven conf to use external Maven and maven conf that has the proxy settings inside, intellij fails to download artifacts from any remote repositories.

Had no problems with intellij-8, this only started after the upgrade. The Maven conf has not changed either.

I have to do a Maven build from command line to get any new dependent artifacts into my local repo then use intellij-9.

The Maven 2.2 integration has issues behind proxy servers.

Comment: I got it to mostly work -- I think the secret it to tell Intellij your config instead of trying to figure it out.

Goto File->Settings-Maven and set all three Maven directories at the bottom.  That got it working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. However, my proxy settings were stored under the environment variable *M2_OPTS*.

As per the above posts, deleting the environment variables stopped IDEA from hanging.

This is under Windows 7, using IntelliJ IDEA CE 12.3

If anyone notices an open bugfix for this please respond with a link.

Comment: Maybe related to this kind of  bug ? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91967