# Connecting to cntlm running on remote machine

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy

I have a PC running cntlm. I am trying to use this cntlm as proxy from another machine. But cntlm listens on local proxy only.

Is there a way, it can work as proxy to external clients too?

The port is open on firewall. I can connect to the machine, which runs on another port, using telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually CNTLM doesn't care if it's local computer or a remote one who wants to connect.

You just have to configure is properly.
I suggest you implement this answer: [How to configure CNTLM properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23962313/234775)

Comment: Thanks. The gateway option worked. Somehow not through the config file,  but the -g option on command line. As documented here http://linux.die.net/man/1/cntlm

Comment: Indeed, to make `Gateway yes` work properly, you must ensure that there is at least one line in config file afterwards, otherwise it gets ignored by `cntlm`. The safest solution is to put some random comment at the end of the file.

Comment: @bagage Thankyou for the trick. I've added a comment to the last line of the config file, in the answer.