# IDEA default artifactory and nexus URLs behind a proxy

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have Intellij IDEA Community 2017.3 installed on a Linux distrib and I need to use an authenticated proxy to get to the Internet. I have a system-wide proxy , and I have configured the IntelliJ proxy and the maven jvm proxy as explained in [Intellij Community can't use http proxy for Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784132/intellij-community-cant-use-http-proxy-for-maven). Maven projects work well (I can get archives on the Internet), and I can get the list of plugins.

When I try to import libraries from maven (under *Project structure > Libraries > + > from Maven*) or when I test the Artifactory or Nexus Service URLs under *Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Remote Jar Repositories*, I cannot get any new library and tests of default urls returns "no reporitories found". In the idea logs, I get a 407 error:

```
2018-01-24 13:37:43,178 [ 284705]   INFO - MavenRepositoryServicesManager - java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required" 
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
    at com.intellij.jarRepository.services.artifactory.ArtifactoryRepositoryService.findArtifacts(ArtifactoryRepositoryService.java:111)
    at com.intellij.jarRepository.services.MavenRepositoryServicesManager.findArtifacts(MavenRepositoryServicesManager.java:121)
    at com.intellij.jarRepository.JarRepositoryManager$2.run(JarRepositoryManager.java:304)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

Note that I have also configured the `settings.xml` file in the `.m2` directory, and tested it outside IntelliJ. It also works fine.

I suppose there is another place where I should indicate proxy info, but I don't know where. My proxy requires user name and password.